# ProcessBuilder cannot find the specified file while Process can

Tags: java, process, processbuilder

I am trying to run a jar file from a Java program and I succeed using `getRuntime()`:

```
Process processAlgo = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java -jar "+algoPath);
```

However when I try using `ProcessBuilder` I get the `The system cannot find the file specified` exception:

```
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("java -jar " + algoPath);
Process processAlgo = builder.start();
```

I tried to change the location of the specified file and also indicated its full path but it won't work. What could cause the problem?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`ProcessBuilder` expects it's parameters to passed in separately.

That is, for each command and argument, `ProcessBuilder` expects to see it as a separate parameter.

Currently you're telling it to run "java -jar what ever the value of algoPath is"...which from `ProcessBuilder`'s perspective, is an invalid command.

Try...

```
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("java",  "-jar", algoPath);
Process processAlgo = builder.start();
```

Instead.

If `algoPath` contains spaces (ie more then one argument), they will need to be separated into individual parameters as well, otherwise your program will not execute, as Java will see the `algoPath` as a single parameter.

Check the [JavaDocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) for more details

Comment: Phew, cause it freaked me out first ;)

Comment: ...also if you have your command stored externally as a single string resource, you may want to use commad.split(" ")

Comment: @xtreye You mean like *"If algoPath contains spaces (ie more then one argument), they will need to be separated into individual parameters as well, otherwise your program will not execute, as Java will see the algoPath as a single parameter."*

Comment: Yes, this is the situation I mean.

Answer (score 0):

Yes the "java" should be your first parameter, and every other argument has to sent in other parameter.

I had a problem with executing this line "bash /path/script.sh arg1 arg2"...
because the first parameter I was passing was "bash /path/script.sh", "arg1", "arg3"... getting the Exception: Command not found by JAVA.

When I separate in parameters each element, then worked fine.
"bash", "/path/script", "arg1", "arg2".