# Cannot run program "query.sh": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: java

When I'm running the code below I get the error:

> Cannot run program "query.sh": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified, Please check below code

I'm not sure how I can diagnose the root cause for its failure. What should I do to resolve the problem?

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(FILE_PATH+SHELL_SCRIPT_NAME,
        DB_INSTANCE,
        DB_USER, 
        DB_PASS, 
        DB_NAME,
        SQL_QUERY, 
        fileFormat.toString());
Process p = pb.start();
p.waitFor();
```

Comment: Make sure `query.sh` is in the classpath, or just give your app a full path to that file.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14999489/processbuilder-cannot-find-the-specified-file-while-process-can

Comment: What are the values of FILE_PATH and SHELL_SCRIPT_NAME?

Comment: if `"query.sh"` is reflecting the exact value of `FILE_PATH+SHELL_SCRIPT_NAME` then this means that `FILE_PATH` is empty and the file your are trying to run `query.sh` is not located in the working directory of your progam. Please check the values of each variable you are using to build the path of the file to be executed and compare it to the location in the filesystem.

Comment: @BackSlash What does the *classpath* has to do with it?

Answer (score 0):

Let me guess: The program works when you run it in eclipse/InteliJ but fails when you build a runnable jar using eclipse/Maven/gradle? In that case, make sure that case, make sure that `query.sh` is in the resource directory of your project (probably called `res/main`.

Otherwise, make sure that `query.sh` is in the working directory of your application or just specify the fully qualified file name of `query.sh`.